# R: Split data.frame by an attribute with multiple categorical values per row to calculate a measure

Tags: r

The following data is provided:

```
> data <- data.frame("randomData"=rnorm(5), "category"=c("A, B","A","C, A","B, C","B"))

  randomData category
1 -0.4963843     A, B
2  1.6351726        A
3 -1.6209544     C, A
4  1.4167151     B, C
5  1.6380250        B
```

My goal is to apply a function on the randomData column to calculate some measures for every category (A, B, C) in the category column. Currently the category column contains multiple categories, which of course leads to the following result:

```
> by(data[,1], data[,"category"], sum)
data[, "category"]: A
[1] 1.635173
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data[, "category"]: A, B
[1] -0.4963843
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data[, "category"]: B
[1] 1.638025
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data[, "category"]: B, C
[1] 1.416715
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data[, "category"]: C, A
[1] -1.620954
```

Now, I can get the unique category values (and new levels) for example in this way:

```
> levels <- levels(as.factor(unlist(strsplit(levels(data[,"category"]),", "))))
```

And I can select the values with respect to a new level.

```
> data[which(grepl(levels[1], data$category)), ]
  randomData category
1 -0.4963843     A, B
2  1.6351726        A
3 -1.6209544     C, A
```

In the next step I would construct a loop to repeat this procedure with every new level and to finally calculate a value (e.g. sum) for every category. But isn't there a better (loop-free) way to split the data based on those categories and to calculate some measure for these groups?

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` and friends is usually a good trick for avoiding loops at the top level.

Here is one way to do it:

```
# Generate the data 
set.seed(100)
data <- data.frame("randomData"=rnorm(5), 
                   "category"=c("A, B","A","C, A","B, C","B"))
# Grab the unique categories
categories <- unique(unlist(sapply(levels(data$category), 
                     function(x){strsplit(x, ", ")})))
# Use sapply to process each category separately
sums <- sapply(categories, 
               function(x){sum(data[grep(x, data$category), "randomData"])})
```

And the result:

```
> data
   randomData category
1 -0.50219235     A, B
2  0.13153117        A
3 -0.07891709     C, A
4  0.88678481     B, C
5  0.11697127        B
> sums
         A          B          C 
-0.4495783  0.5015637  0.8078677
```

Now you can measure the data (by category) in any way you want - just replace the `sum` function in the third line.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this with a fairly easy syntax:

```
library(splitstackshape)

# slightly 'simpler' randomData
# to make it easier to check if this gives the desired results
df <- data.frame(randomData = 1:5,
                  category = c("A, B", "A", "C, A", "B, C", "B"))
df
#   randomData category
# 1          1     A, B
# 2          2        A
# 3          3     C, A
# 4          4     B, C
# 5          5        B    

# split the concatenated column, and reshape from wide to long format
df2 <- concat.split.multiple(data = df, split.cols = "category", direction = "long")
df2

# calculate sum per category
aggregate(randomData ~ category, data = df2, sum)
#   category randomData
# 1        A          6
# 2        B         10
# 3        C          7
```